# mysqli prepare select query with OR operator doesn't work

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, or-operator

I am creating an inbox messaging system in PHP like the FaceBook ones. For this reason I created 2 tables in a MySQL database, called `conversation` and `inbox_messages`.

The concept is when a user wants to start a conversation with another user, I insert a record to the `conversation` table with unique id that have 4 rows:

- `id`
- `user_one`
- `user_two`
- `date`

What I would like to do: when a user logs in, grab the username session that is been created from login and then, with a mysqli prepared statement and a select query, check if the user is in `conversation` table with an another one. If so, append in a DIV.

The problem I face is that with query string and especially with the OR OPERATOR, seems that doesn't work. What I would like to do in query is: if `user_one` is equal with `$_SESSION['username']` OR `user_two` is equal with the same `$_SESSION['username']`, so if the logged in user is in the table row `user_one` or row `user_two` append the conversation id.

```
$par1 = $_SESSION['username'];
$par2 = $_SESSION['username'];

//$par1 and $par2 holds the same name

$query = "SELECT id FROM conversation WHERE user_one = ? OR user_two = ?";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $par1, $par2);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    $stmt->fetch();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        echo $id;
    }

    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Ok i will do that, but i would like to ask, is my $query correct, maybe i should write it differently, because its the first  time i use OR operator

Comment: The query itself looks ok (one _could_ argue about having the fields user_one and user_two in that table instead of modelling the relation with another table, but anyway....). What is the result you get and in what way does it deviate from what you expect?

Comment: I don't get any result. What i expect is to grab the unique id between the two users and then search to my second table where conversation id is equal to the id i get and find all the messages between the two users

Comment: From my query i get the follow error ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? OR user_two = ?** @Fred-ii-

Comment: this tells me your connection isn't `mysqli_`, but probably `mysql_`.

Comment: No for sure is mysqli, maybe there is a problem with ? in where clause @Fred-ii-

Comment: then you didn't connect to the database and that is unknown.

Comment: Works fine for me, http://pastebin.com/eqEhVHpb , just prints `1 3` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Instead of :

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $par1, $par2);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    $stmt->fetch();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        echo $id;
    }

    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();


     }
```

I replace it with :

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $par1, $par2);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
       echo $id;

     }


    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();


     }
```

And works!

Comment: *"`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?`"* - That doesn't support the error you told me you were getting earlier.

Comment: Yes, the `$stmt->num_rows == 1` part looked strange, but this doesn't explain the actual error message. (I assume you've fiddled with the query in the meantime and had some [unrelated] error in it at one point.)

Comment: Thank you @Fred-ii- i will search more detailed

Comment: Thank you @VolkerK  for your advice